# R - Splitting a column into two based on values in a column

Tags: r

I have a column Date which has the values like "2099-12-01" and NA.
I have another column Time which has the values like time and some character string.

**This is how the data looks currently:**

[image: image 1]

I want to separate column Date into two column named "Date" and "Account" where all the date like values should go under Date column and all the NA values should go under Comment column.

And I want to separate Column TIME into two columns named "Time" and "Comment" where all the time like values should go under "Time" and all the character strings should go under "Comment" column

I am using below code

```
separate(Date, c("Date", "Account"), sep = "%d/%m/%Y" , remove = TRUE ) %>%
separate(Time, c("Time", "Comment"), sep = "$$:$$"  , remove = TRUE ) %>%
```

But it doesn't seem to work for Time column.
Need help in defining the separator and any other approach in splitting the columns.

I expect the output to be like

**Expected Output:**

[image: image 2]

Comment: I fail to see the pattern. Why should `9/6/2019` and `9:40` be on the same row?

Comment: @ AkselaA , Its not manadatory for them to be in the same row but they can be on the same row since its the Punch In data for a user. We can ignore the criteria for them to be in the same row. For now, m just focused on getting them separated into two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the splitting using ifelse. But any other approach using separator or spilt etc is welcome.

new_pdf$Time <- ifelse (nchar(new_pdf$Time) == 5, new_pdf$Time, NA ) %>%
new_pdf$Comment <- ifelse (nchar(new_pdf$Time) > 5, new_pdf$Time, NA)

where new_pdf is the name of the data.frame in which splitting was required